# Remove re-occuring text strings

Tags: r, regex

I am new to R and have searched the forum for almost 2 hours now without getting it to work for me.

My problem: I have a long text string scraped from internet. As I scraped code for images were included. The are coded in a way that they start with `"Embed from Getty Images"` and ends with `"false })});\n"`. I would like to remove everything in between those strings. I have tried `gsub()` as per:

```
AmericanTexts3 <- gsub("Embed.*})});\n", "", AmericanTexts)
```

But what happens then is that they remove everything between the first picture and the last picture. Do anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy regular expression.

Try

```
AmericanTexts3<-gsub("Embed.*?})});\n","",AmericanTexts)
```

The `?` matches the first occurence of the second part of the regex, so that only the part between the matches should be removed.